# Cross-thread operation not valid with background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I hope this won't be a hard one.

I'm trying to achieve that while a gridview is populated, my progress bar works with marquee style.

This is what I have until now:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

and then:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    dt.Rows.Clear();
    fillData();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;

    button1.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

But this is giving me a cross thread error in the last line of this piece of code:

```
public void fillData()
{            
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    string sql = "CC_SP_ReadTags'" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text +"','','Timestamp ASC','TIMESTEP=30,2'";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    myGrid.DataSource = dt;           
}
```

Any help on how to handle it would be really appreciated, please consider that I'm a newbie still.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Use Dispatcher.Invoke method to call fill method

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code when you post. Look at the preview and think about whether that's really the way other people will want to read the code. I've fixed it now, but please pay attention in the future.

Comment: Next up: you have a possible SQL injection attack vulnerability at the moment. Never put values into SQL like that - use parameterized SQL.

Comment: Then: read up and start to follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Finally: I'd suggest you make your background worker create a *new* DataTable. When it's filled that, then it can finish - and in `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` you can set the data source to the new `DataTable`, as *that's* what will affect the UI, and has to be done in the UI thread. You might want to look at using `async`/`await` at some point, too...

Comment: @tabby, fill is not the problem - it's accessing myGrid on the UI thread...

Comment: @CoolBots fill method is getting called from DoWork method not from completed event

Comment: @tabby, DoWork method runs in a separate thread; myGrid is a UI control, and is not accessible from this thread. The code is failing on trying to access the UI control, not filling a datatable; OP actually stated that in the question.

Comment: Thanks to all for your effort in helping me here. I managed to get this working by moving the line `myGrid.DataSource = dt;` from the fillData method to the bw_RunWorkerCompleted section. Thanks again and sorry for bad text formatting at the beginning.

Comment: @CoolBots fillData is in DoWork so it will run in Background thread thats what i said...and accessing UI control there from it will cause an error.

Comment: @tabby, lol, I just got the confusion - your original comment says "fill method", not "filldata" - I thought you're referring to `adapter.Fill (dt)` line in filldata() method - I just realized you were talking about the entire filldata() method!

Comment: @CoolBots Lol Yes...